# Fit Large Text in a Quizz Layout

Tags: gui-design, android, material-design

I'm trying to make a Quizz section for my app in android 
the problem is that it may have large Texts in it and i want to make it easy to read and to answer 
i came out with this design

[image: the Design i came out with]

but i think it's kinda buggy cuz the user needs to press the button to enter his answer
any ideas ? please i need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the "example" and "definition" as headings of the boxes. It can give you enough room to play around with a long string like this.

There are other ways as well to make it pleasing and usable at the same time. Check primer app by Google.

[image]

Comment: the font u used ?

Comment: @Sohaib font is montserrat

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to simplify the layout to make things looks and appear clearer, you need to place the title on top of the text and align it to the left, also try to differentiate between the definition and the example section in terms of text size and color, also use simple separate between the two sections. And for the top note try to make it in an informative way and don't give it that importance.

[image]